# Strange behaviour with iOS kABPersonModificationDateProperty, seems to update all the time

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

I'm seeing really weird behaviour in my iOS app using the ABAddressBook library. Wondering if anyone can give me some insight into whats happening in the background or if I have a logic error I just can't see.

Long story short I'm making a VOIP app that relies heavily on importing the user's contacts. I keep an online backup of these that are also used in conjunction with push notifications.

As they are modified on the phone I need to send an update request to the server to keep them accurate. The problem is many user devices are frequently spamming the server with very large blocks of contacts, at random intervals. One day it will be 50+ contacts, 5 mins later another 10, then it will be a month before a single one is updated. I have asked a few users that are friends and they can't recall modifying half of their address book over night.

My code is very simple, I store an `NSDate` every time I am required to send an update to the server, e.g. addition, modification or deletion. I know there is a callback that triggers when the address book has been updated, but this requires keeping a reference to the address book in memory at all times. I've done some testing and if the app crashes or the user kills the app, I loose any updates. Given its a background running VOIP app I feel it is possible people will kill it on an occasion to save battery or whatever. So for that reason I loop through all the contacts checking the `kABPersonModificationDateProperty` property against the last `NSDate` I have recorded. If the modified is newer I begin my update, like so.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSDate *lastChecked = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[PListData readStringFromFile:@"lastContactsArchive"]];


CFDateRef modifyDate = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonModificationDateProperty);
...
...
else if ([(__bridge NSDate*)modifyDate compare:lastChecked]==NSOrderedDescending) // if modified after last check, create new contact and update
{
   ...
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing, is the modification date only updated when the name / phone numbers / email etc are changed ? Are they modified when iCloud syncs for example ? is a counter updated if they call the person on the phone ? etc.

I've tried debugging on 3 phones and all behave as I would expect. I'm really drawing a blank here and the server isn't happy with me so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: still have the problem ?

Comment: unfortunately the project I was working on has been postponed for the minute so didn't get to look into this further. But yes, spent 2 days searching and can't seem to get any other info and can't explain why else the code would be doing this. Struggling to believe it does this as it sounds ridiculous

Comment: To downvoters, please explain why your downvoting my question. It was upvoted a few times so I would think you should have a good reason for doing so, care to share ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue for modification date being update whenever I am changing my iPhone's language, but I haven't updated my address book, any suggestions to solve that

Comment: @Talha Sorry no, this project was cancelled, never found a solution. It seems to be impossible to fix other than check all details of the contact to see has the data changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacts may also update in background when iphone syncs contacts with iCloud / CardDav / Gmail / Exchange account.

Note that it also may happen while your app is running, so you should subscribe for address book updates.

Comment: this isn't at all what i'm asking. I frequently run the above check, I will always catch the updated contacts this way so long as the user keeps using the app for anything. What I'm asking is when does the low level "modified" flag get set, it seems to set itself all the time for no reason

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin That's what i'm saying, it does set all the time if an iCloud account is defined, which is most cases. iCloud syncs contacts every few hours and may reset the flag. Also, having contacts on an exchange / gmail account would do the same.

Comment: Any workarounds? (Besides disabling iCloud?) I was counting on that property to figure if a contact changed :(