# kABPersonModificationDateProperty return wrong date?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, addressbook

i'm trying to get last date that contact update in.

but it is always return the current date for contact.

```
ABRecordRef record = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(myAddressBook, recordId);

NSDate *lastModif=(__bridge NSDate *)(ABRecordCopyValue(record,kABPersonModificationDateProperty));

//NSLog(@"%@",(__bridge NSDate *)(ABRecordCopyValue(record,kABPersonModificationDateProperty)));
//2013-07-10 12:52:08 +0000
```

I found [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715032/strange-behaviour-with-ios-kabpersonmodificationdateproperty-seems-to-update-al) question but still no answer.

**Update:**

If i call `ABAddressBookRevert(myAddressBook);` befor my code it give a correct date.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715032/strange-behaviour-with-ios-kabpersonmodificationdateproperty-seems-to-update-al

Comment: like i say before "I found similar question but still no answer"

Comment: Like it is saying it is indeed doing some iCloud backup which is correctly modifying the date.

Comment: @NiravBhatt but this not what really happened, turn iCloud off and it is the same result.

Comment: Did you try NSLog lastModif var instead of the long expression in comment?

Comment: Yes, and it is the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33246/discussion-between-omarj-and-nirav-bhatt)

Comment: well I am off for any suggestions as of now. If anything will come back.